# How to create worklight project in eclipse dynamically?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

I googled about how to create eclipse project dynamically, but most of them explained about creating Java projects. I wants to create worklight project programatically. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with Worklight 6.0 and 6.1. However the next release of Worklight, v6.2, will provide a CLI that will allow you to create and manage projects from command line without using Worklight Studio.

[http://www.websphereusergroup.org/go/article/view/articles/265479/impact_2014:_mobile_strategy_and_ibm_worklight_6.2](http://www.websphereusergroup.org/go/article/view/articles/265479/impact_2014%3a_mobile_strategy_and_ibm_worklight_6.2)

Comment: You have any idea when Worklight 6.2 will be released?

Comment: Early June. Next month.